# mp3 playing services or server(link ending with .mp3)

Tags: php, android, web-services, mp3, server

In my app I need to play online mp3 which I am successfully playing using MediaPlayer in android using this link

http://www.virginmegastore.me/Library/Music/CD_001214/Tracks/Track1.mp3

I have many mp3's that that I need to upload on server which provide the services as the above link mentioned.

I have tried to upload them on Google Drive, Also tried soundcloud but their behaviour was different.

I need the same service like this link http://www.virginmegastore.me/Library/Music/CD_001214/Tracks/Track1.mp3 provides.

Anyone know any website having this behaviour ?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE after -ve downvotes(showing what I tried)**

I used picosong.com which produces this link http://picosong.com/5Nt9 , The above link does not ends with ****.mp3 & to make this desired link I perhaps need a php server !

I searched on net & found these websites

- http://www.webestools.com/mp3-player-flash-swf-generator-flash-mp3-player-fla-script-play-music-mp3-site.html
- I tried this link http://www.strangecube.com/audioplay/ also which then produced this code

Generated by AudioPlay Online Generator (http://www.strangecube.com/audioplay/)

```
<div>
       <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0" width="30" height="30">
           <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="http://www.strangecube.com/audioplay/online/audioplay.swf?file=http://picosong.com/5Nt9&auto=yes&sendstop=no&repeat=1&buttondir=http://www.strangecube.com/audioplay/online/alpha_buttons/classic&bgcolor=0x000000&mode=playpause">
           <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high><PARAM NAME=wmode VALUE=transparent>
           <embed src="http://www.strangecube.com/audioplay/online/audioplay.swf?file=http://picosong.com/5Nt9&auto=yes&sendstop=no&repeat=1&buttondir=http://www.strangecube.com/audioplay/online/alpha_buttons/classic&bgcolor=0x000000&mode=playpause" quality=high wmode=transparent width="30" height="30" align="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">  
           </embed>
    </object>
</div><!-- End of generated code -->
```

I tried it running in the localhost xampp which does not show anything, no errors but not running

What am I doing wrong ?

All I just want is the .mp3 ending link having exact the same visibility as this link http://www.virginmegastore.me/Library/Music/CD_001214/Tracks/Track1.mp3
 because only this type of link can be streamed live in android.

Help !!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Please see my updated question, perhaps its now not off-topic here

Comment: Explain downvote please...

Comment: Your question is a little bit confuse. You are able to play mp3 stream music on your application.. And now.. do you want to store mp3 files on the cloud? Try to contextualize and describe better your problem and what are you trying to do to solve it.

Comment: @cassioso All I just want is the .mp3 ending link having exact the same visibility as this link http://www.virginmegastore.me/Library/Music/CD_001214/Tracks/Track1.mp3 do you know how to achieve this, then please tell

Comment: @VivekWarde : Hi, I have gone through your whole post and what i have understand is you want to store mp3 file from this url http://www.virginmegastore.me/Library/Music/CD_001214/Tracks/Track1.mp3 and want to make it visible on your server or url. Or you just want to play this mp3 file on your server. Please make me understand.

Comment: @NeerajKumar I want a new link which plays my own mp3 (like this example here www.virginmegastore.me/Library/Music/CD_001214/Tracks/Track1.mp3 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided to the MP3 file was just... a link to an MP3 file. Every client will interpret it differently.

So you can:

1. Store the file in the server and provide a link to the file - no PHP involved.
2. Deliver using PHP

   ```
   header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
   readfile($mp3_filepath);
   ```
3. You mentioned Google Drive. You can deliver the file directly by:

   1. Putting the files in a folder and make the folder **public**. Not "anyone with the link" - **public**.
   2. Redirecting the user to `https://googledrive.com/host/[FOLDER_ID]/[MP3_FILE].mp3`

Have fun.

Comment: oh ! that was so simple... ur 1st point makes it. BTW please tell about the second point more i do not understand

Comment: @VivekWarde In 2nd you mean Deliver using PHP?

Comment: Like you said "to make this desired link I perhaps need a php server". It reads a file (loads it) and sets a header to tell the browser (client) that the file is in audio format. There are not many advantages in your case.